# Problem in rendering triangle mesh with reflections in webgl and opengles

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, rendering, webgl2

iam currently writing a ray tracer with triangle intersection. i have exported the mesh as a .raw format just to have coordinates of each vertex.
And i have noticed a thing that when i rotate the camera it kind of showing occluded mesh.

i post my triangle intersection function below in my fragment shader

```
bool hitTriangle(vec3 orig,vec3 dir,vec3 a,vec3 b,vec3 c,out vec3 uvt,out vec3 triangleNormal){
   float eps=1e-8;
   vec3 ab=b-a;
   vec3 ac=c-a;

   triangleNormal = normalize(cross(ab,ac));
   vec3 n=cross(dir,ac);

   float det=dot(ab,n);
   // if the determinant is negative the triangle is backfacing
   // if the determinant is close to 0, the ray misses the triangl
   if(det<=eps){ return false;}
   
   vec3 ao=orig-a;
   float u=dot(ao,n)/det;
   if(u<0.0 || u>1.0){ return false;}
    
   vec3 e=cross(ao,ab);
   float v=dot(dir,e)/det;
   if(v<0.0||u+v>1.0){ return false;}

   float t= dot(ac,e)/det;
   uvt = vec3(u,v,t);
   return true;
}
```

below it the hitScene function where i go throuth all the mesh and check for intersections

```
bool hitScene(Ray R_, out vec3 hitPos, out vec3 normal, out Material material, Sphere lightSource){  // na thimithw na thesw to isShpere false stin trace synartisi
        
    vec4 a = vec4(0.0), b = vec4(0.0), c = vec4(0.0);
    float mindist = -1000.;
    bool weHitSomething = false;
    vec3 hitPos1 = vec3(0.),triangleNormal = vec3(0.,0.,0.), sphereNormal;
    

    //here we chck all the mesh if we hit a triangle if the mesh and we keep the closest hitpoint
    for (int i = 0; i < vertsCount; i += 3) {
       
        a = texelFetch(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0);
        b = texelFetchOffset(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(1, 0));
        c = texelFetchOffset(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(2, 0));

        vec3 uvt;
        bool isHit = hitTriangle(R_.orig,R_.dir, a.xyz,b.xyz,c.xyz,uvt, triangleNormal);
        if (isHit) {
            vec3 intersect = R_.orig + R_.dir*uvt.z;
            float z = intersect.z;
            if (z>mindist) {
                hitPos1 = intersect;
                
                mindist = z;
                weHitSomething = true;
                material.type = METAL;
                material.albedo = vec3(.0, .8, .8);
                normal = triangleNormal;
                hitPos = hitPos1;
            }
        }      
    }      
    
    return weHitSomething;
}
```

and below is the Trace function that loops through the traces

```
//Trace is the main function of the max bounces
vec3 Trace(out Ray ray, Sphere lightSource){

    vec3 hitPos, normal;
    bool isShpere;
    Material material;
    vec3 color = vec3(1.);
    vec3 attenuation = vec3(1.);
    vec3 light = vec3(1.,1.,1.), shadow = vec3(1.,1.,1.);

    //this if for every ray to bounce 4 times.(hopefully)
    for(int i=0; i< MAX_BOUNCES; i++){
        
        // we check if we hit something
        if(hitScene(ray, hitPos, normal, material, lightSource)){
  
            //we calculate the new direction
            vec3 direction = normalize(reflect(ray.dir, normal));
                
            ray = Ray(hitPos, direction); 
             
            color *= material.albedo * attenuation*hitPos;
            attenuation *= material.albedo;    
        }

        else{
            color = attenuation;
        }
    }

    return color;
}
```

and after that iam getting something like that:
[image]
As you see I am getting reflections but i am seeing the cube as well inside the sphere. Does that mean i fail the ray-triangle intersection tests? or the min distance is not correct??

What might be the source of the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide (a link) to a [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @rabbid76 https://jsfiddle.net/dominuss/qLcp0rn2/5/ is this a minimal complete example? if not i can try. The thing is i modified the triangle intersection tests but now i cannot see reflections. at all. Dont know if my " camera" is pointing wrong.

Comment: Update, there is a problem in my trace function 100% because it goes 90% in the else of the check in the hitScene if i keep the for loop with the bounces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is won't solve all your issues, but it is one part of the answer.

In your code there is a basic misunderstanding of [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system). The barycentric coordinates are not a coordinate, but they are 3 values in range [0, 1]. Imagine a  barycentric coordinates as 3 weights, which weight the 3 corner points of a triangle.

The sum of the 3 scales of a barycentric coordinate is 1:

```
b.x + b.x + b.z == 1
```

If a triangle is defined by three points `A`, `B` and `C`, then the point `X` on the triangle, which is defined by the barycentric coordinate can be calculated by the formula:

```
X =  A * b.x + B * b.y + C * b.z
```

This means the calculation of the intersection `distance` in `hitScene` has to be adapted as follows:

```c
vec3 intersect = a.xyz * uvt.x + b.xyz * uvt.y + c.xyz * uvt.z;
```

Thi distance to the origin of the ray is the is the length of the vector form the origin to the intersection point i the direction of the ray.
In general I would calculate this somehow like that:

```c
float z = dot(intersect - R_.orig, normalize(R_.dir));
```

---

Further the algorithm to calculate the barycentric coordinates looks odd. I'm very sure it has to be `uvt = vec3(t, u, v)` rather than `uvt = vec3(u, v, t);`. But this has to be investigated further.

The intersection of a triangle and a ray can be calculated as follows:

[image]

The ray is defined by a point `R0` and a direction `D`.
The plane is defined by a triangle with the three points `PA`, `PB`, and `PC`.

The normal vector of the plane can be calculated by the cross product of 2 legs of the triangle:

```
N  =  normalize( cross(PC-PA, PB-PA)
```

The normal distance `n` of the point `R0` to the plane is:

```
n  =  | R0 - PA | * cos(alpha)  =  dot(PA - R0, N)
```

It follows that the distance `d` of the intersection point `X` to the origin of the ray R0 is:

```
d  =  n / cos(beta)  =  n / dot(D, N)
```

The intersection point `X` is:

```
X  =  R0 + D * d  =  R0 + D * dot(PA - R0, N) / dot(D, N)
```

Applying the to your code, I recommend  to use the following function `hitTriangle`:

- The return value is `true` if the ray intersects the triangle primitive in the positive direction of ray (`dir`) after the origin of the ray (`orig`).
- The output `N` is the normal vector of the plane which is defined by the triangle.
- The output `uvt` are the [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of the triangle.
- The output `x` is the intersection point on the triangle.
- And the output `dist` is the distance from the origin of the ray (`orig`) to the intersection point `x`.

Note, the ray direction (`dir`) has to be normalized. The output values have only a meaning if the function returns `true`.

```c
bool hitTriangle(
    vec3 orig, vec3 dir, vec3 a, vec3 b, vec3 c,
    out vec3 uvt, out vec3 N, out vec3 x, out float dist) {

    float eps=1e-8;

    vec3 ab = b - a;
    vec3 ac = c - a;

    N = normalize(cross(ab, ac));

    dist = dot(a - orig, N) / dot(dir, N);
    x    = orig + dir * dist;

    vec3 ax = x - a;

    float d00 = dot(ab, ab);
    float d01 = dot(ab, ac);
    float d11 = dot(ac, ac);
    float d20 = dot(ax, ab);
    float d21 = dot(ax, ac);

    float denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01; // determinant

    // if the determinant is negative the triangle is backfacing
    // if the determinant is close to 0, the ray misses the triangl
    if ( denom <= eps )
        return false;

    uvt.y = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom;
    if ( uvt.y < 0.0 || uvt.y > 1.0 )
        return false;

    uvt.z = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom;
    if ( uvt.z < 0.0 || uvt.z > 1.0 )
        return false;

    uvt.x = 1.0 - uvt.y - uvt.z;
    if ( uvt.x < 0.0 || uvt.x > 1.0 )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

---

Use the hit test (`hitTriangle`) in the function `hitScene` as follows:

```c
bool hitScene(Ray R_, out vec3 hitPos, out vec3 normal, out Material material, Sphere lightSource){  // na thimithw na thesw to isShpere false stin trace synartisi

    vec4 a = vec4(0.0), b = vec4(0.0), c = vec4(0.0);
    float mindist = 1000.;
    bool weHitSomething = false;
    vec3 hitPos1 = vec3(0.),triangleNormal = vec3(0.,0.,0.), sphereNormal;

    vec3 ray_dir = normalize(R_.dir);

    //here we chck all the mesh if we hit a triangle if the mesh and we keep the closest hitpoint
    for (int i = 0; i < vertsCount; i += 3) {

        a = texelFetch(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0);
        b = texelFetchOffset(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(1, 0));
        c = texelFetchOffset(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(2, 0));

        vec3 uvt;
        vec3 intersect;
        float z;
        bool isHit = hitTriangle(R_.orig, ray_dir, a.xyz, b.xyz, c.xyz, uvt, triangleNormal, intersect, z);
        if (isHit)
        {
            if (z < mindist && z > 0.001)
            {
                hitPos1 = intersect;

                mindist = z;
                weHitSomething = true;
                material.type = METAL;
                material.albedo = vec3(.0, .8, .8);
                normal = triangleNormal;
                hitPos = hitPos1;
            }
        }
    }

    return weHitSomething;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Jojendersie/gpugi/blob/5d18526c864bbf09baca02bfab6bcec97b7e1210/gpugi/shader/intersectiontests.glsl#L63 do you find this intersection test right? i have tested some and with the maths i know this worked the best for me(i mean the one i kept)...

Comment: i also need an explanation of what the out parameters are, i dont know what the float hit is.

Comment: @ThodorisKoutsis See the extension to the answer.

Comment: ill test your solution asap.

Comment: You saved the day. Thank you!!

Comment: @ThodorisKoutsis You're welcome. I'm pleased to help you.

Comment: i need another clarification. Because i want to produde "smooth" edges i need to take into account the barycentric coords. So how to i do that? in the hitTriangle function after i find that the triangle is hit then the normal produced is N = vec3(N.x*uvt.x, N.y*uvt.y, N.z*uvt.z) or i take into account of the other 2 vertex normals? i mean how do i interpolate between the vertex normals to get a "smoother" face normal? https://jsfiddle.net/dominuss/fsgd6La3/5/ (line 248) same example with vertex normas loaded. i want to interpolate between the triangle face..

Comment: i did this normal = aN.xyz*uvt.x + bN.xyz*uvt.y + cN.xyz*uvt.z; and to me it seems correct. here is the result https://jsfiddle.net/dominuss/fsgd6La3/9/